# iptables error in android: iptables-save and iptables-restore not working

Tags: android, linux-kernel, iptables, saving-data, netfilter

I have compiled Linux for android emulator with full netfilter functionality enabled. And got a iptables binary after building android from source.

When i push this binary to the emulator

i can execute commands like below successfully.

```
iptables -L
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -s www.google.com -j DROP
```

with this error:

```
# # iptables -L
getsockopt for multiport failed strangely: No such file or directory
getsockopt for multiport failed strangely: No such file or directory
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
#
```

and

```
# iptables -A INPUT -s www.google.com -j DROP
getsockopt for multiport failed strangely: No such file or directory
getsockopt for multiport failed strangely: No such file or directory
FIX ME! implement getgrnam() bionic/libc/bionic/stubs.c:344
```

but atleast the above commands they work!

but when i try

```
iptables-save     or
iptables-restore
```

i get error saying

```
iptables-save: not found
```

In my config file

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MULTIPORT=m
```

what is the problem..?? and how can i enable full iptables functionality in android or how can i save the current active iptables rules safely and reload them when next reboot.

please help. thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` are different binaries, hence why they don't contain spaces (as opposed to `iptables -L`, for example, which does).

Comment: actually i meant to write iptables-save or iptables-retore as a sentence. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've added to my Android.mk in order to get both iptables-save and iptables-retore.
It compiles ok on android 4.0.3.

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# iptables-save


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include/

LOCAL_CFLAGS:=-DNO_SHARED_LIBS=1
LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-DALL_INCLUSIVE
LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-DXTABLES_INTERNAL
# Accommodate arm-eabi-4.4.3 tools that don't set __ANDROID__
LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-D__ANDROID__

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    iptables-save.c iptables.c xshared.c

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE:=iptables-save

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
    libext \
    libext4 \
    libip4tc \
    libxtables

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)


#----------------------------------------------------------------
# iptables-restore


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include/

LOCAL_CFLAGS:=-DNO_SHARED_LIBS=1
LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-DALL_INCLUSIVE
LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-DXTABLES_INTERNAL
# Accommodate arm-eabi-4.4.3 tools that don't set __ANDROID__
LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-D__ANDROID__

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    iptables-restore.c iptables.c xshared.c

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE:=iptables-restore

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
    libext \
    libext4 \
    libip4tc \
    libxtables

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` binaries are not built by the default Android system makefiles.

You'll need to add rules to the `Android.mk` file in `$mydroid/external/iptables/` to build them.  The source files, `iptables-save.c` and `iptables-restore.c` are already in that directory.

Untested, but to build `iptables-save`, add something like this to the end of `Android.mk`. Rinse and repeat for `iptables-restore`:

```
#
# Build iptables-save
#

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/ \
    $(KERNEL_HEADERS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS:=-DNO_SHARED_LIBS
LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-DIPTABLES_VERSION=\"1.3.7\"

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    iptables-save.c 

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS:=debug
LOCAL_MODULE:=iptables-save

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
    libiptc \
    libext

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much David! but when i do this i get many errors like:

Comment: sorry, i was not able to enter the output in comments, so i put that in answer.

Comment: if android team has modified iptables source, to exclude iptables-save than they must have modified some source files  which call functions in iptables-save(i think). May be because of that, the error comes.

Comment: I checked iptables 1.3.7 sourcecode from netfilter. It seems that android source has its own modified iptables. Like, the file iptables-1.3.7/extension/libipt_connmark.c  is changed to libipt_2connmark.c ,, So, is there any way to solve the problem??